# How can you avoid redundant call while waiting for element visibility

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io

I currently have a test script using WebdriverIO that clicks on a button and waits for a popup to display. The purpose of the test is to make sure the element is displayed after a click, but since it is asynchronous I must wait till it is displayed.

But if I wait until the element is displayed my assertion will always pass if waitForVisible is successful. If it is not successful it will always throw an exception on the waitForVisible command and the assertion will never execute.

Here is an example of the code:

```
browser.click(btnElement)
browser.waitForVisible(popupElement)
expect(browser.isVisible(popupElement)).to.be.true
```

Is there a different way to tell the expect statement to retry/wait until the element is visible so the assertion is not useless?

Comment: Just remove the assert... as you said, it's redundant.

Comment: But what good is a test without an assertion?

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be confusing the purpose of **[assertions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assertion_(software_development))**, or misusing them, specifically in your example. You should only use assertions when you have the **certainty** that the *thing* (`WebElement`, `text`, `attribute` of an element, etc.) you want to verify contains the expected *type of value* (which you return into your `assert`, or `expect` statement for the final validation => *the output is the desired one*).

Assertions validate a *static* value, they don't poll the DOM. That's why you have tools like `.waitForVisible()`, `waitForText()`, or more importantly `.waitUntil()` (which offers more flexibility).

Granted, the `expect` assertion-style provided by **[ChaiJS](http://chaijs.com/guide/styles/#expect)** might have a confusing lexicon (`expect` could be taken out of context: it is expecting of the `WebElement` to be visible). Just use them for validating outputs of different commands, not states of `WebElements`, or other dynamic/changing elements.

---

That being said, as a *best-practice*, you should **always** wrap your commands (e.g.: `.click()`) into a `.waitUntil()` block and assure the `WebElement` is ready for the action you're about to perform:

- is it **rendered** in the DOM by the front-end logic? (use `.isExisting()`)
- is it **visible** in the DOM? (you ***cannot** click on elements which aren't visible in the `viewport`)
- is it **clickable**? (or w/e other action you want to perform on it...)

In the end, a idiomatic action (in our case `.click()`) should look like this:

```
browser.waitUntil(() => {
    browser.isExisting(locator);
}, timeout, "Oups! An error occured.\nReason: element ('" + locator + "') does not exist");
browser.waitUntil(() => {
    browser.isVisible(locator);
}, timeout, "Oups! An error occured.\nReason: element ('" + locator + "') is not visible");
browser.waitUntil(() => {
    browser.click(locator);
}, timeout, "Oups! An error occured.\nReason: element ('" + locator + "') could not be clicked");
```

You can wrap the whole thing into a **[custom-command](http://webdriver.io/api/utility/addCommand.html)** and use it w/e you want. Say good-bye to flaky tests! **:)**

* Selenium is a **user-centric** web-automation tool, thus all actions are performed as if a user would (a user cannot click on *elements that aren't visible*, a user *cannot click on multiple elements* at the same time, or fill in an `input` field by typing a whole word, or a whole paragraph, etc.)

Comment: If I understand you correctly you are saying that you should only use asserts/expects to validate values? But I have seen many examples of people using assertions to check if elements are visible/clickable. If clicking this button creates a popup with content which is unknown (via CMS?) then I cannot know the value, but I can still validate that it is displayed. Yes, it will pass even if it is empty, but there is no other way for me to know what content will be served inside the popup. If I can only assert known values, how can I write a test for this?

Comment: Your answer doesn't make a lot of sense. Why would you need to assert something that you are *certain* will pass? That's the whole point of the assert to make sure that it does pass or errors when it doesn't. I don't know what you mean by *static* value... if the value never changes, there's no point in asserting it. That's like having an assert that `pi` still equals `3.14.`... you would never do that. It's not a best practice to always wrap commands in a wait. Please post a link that states such.

Comment: And that down-vote @JeffC **:)** that's a d!$% move man! Very, very disappointing attitude man.

Comment: @iamdanchiv I see what you are saying, but can't say that I agree, specifically this: "Just use them for validating outputs of different commands, not states of WebElements." If the only purpose of a button on the page is to display some content unknown to the user why would it be wrong to assert the visibility of that element? If a user cannot access an element because it is not visible then that is missing functionality that will ruin my user experience. I have even seen this example used in documentation: http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.isDisplayed

Comment: @iamdanchiv I do like the idea of wrapping commands in wait statements, but I thought WebdriverIO was supposed to be able to resolve asynchronous commands with promise chaining built into the framework? Wouldn't adding an a wait statement to every command bloat the execution time of the suite?

Comment: @iamdanchiv I have read your response and while I will be proceeding by wrapping the command to prevent timeouts I also disagree with your approach on asserting the state of elements on the page. Until I can verify this as a best practice, which I have been unable to in all of my online research, I cannot mark your answer as correct. If anything JeffC's response is more inline with what we will be doing. Also demanding closing a question without further discussion after taunting another user is kind of rude.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know WebdriverIO but I would assume that it has something akin to a `try-catch`. Wrap your wait in a `try-catch`. If it succeeds, `Assert.pass()` or the equivalent. If it times out, an exception will be thrown so in your `catch` for the timeout put an `Assert.fail()` or the equivalent.

---

I've never used ChaiJS but I did take a look at [the documentation](http://chaijs.com/api/assert/#method_isok) and found a couple things you should be able to use.

```
assert.isOk(false, 'this will fail');
```

This is from the documentation and should be the equivalent to what I'm familiar with, `Assert.Fail()`. One would assume that a slight adjustment the following would be the equivalent to `Assert.Pass()`,

```
assert.isOk(true, 'this will pass?');
```

If that doesn't work for some reason, you can use the below from the documentation.

```
assert.isNotOk(false, 'this will pass');
```

Comment: This pretty much sums up how I feel regarding your answer: **[here](https://imgur.com/a/Sc5wn)**. And as a professional-tip, advanced tip when you're *selling an idea, solution, concept*, or *debating someone*, **never** start by saying you know nothing about the thing you are about to make a objective statement about. See the paradox here Jeff?!

Comment: @iamdanchiv I use C# and Java Selenium. WebdriverIO is language bandings for Selenium that I don't program in. The concept still applies, no? It's a programming concept that extends to other languages.

Comment: @JeffC We've implemented the try-catch but unfortunately we don't see ChaiJS using a pass/fail function. Perhaps Im missing it in the documentation.

Comment: @wco-lalka I don't know ChaiJS but I did take a look at the documentation and found a couple things I think you can use as equivalents. I've updated my answer with some samples from the documentation.